Java tests: only first answer working. What should I change?
@Test
void testRowX() {
    // given

    String sizeOfBoardString = "3\n2";
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sizeOfBoardString.getBytes());
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(sizeOfBoardString.getBytes()));

    // when
    OutputComputer outputComputer = new OutputComputer();
    outputComputer.gameStart();
    outputComputer.gameType();
    InputSelector inputSelector = new InputSelector();
    int boardSize = inputSelector.boardType();

    StartGame startGame = new StartGame();
    startGame.runGame(boardSize, boardSize);

    String whoWin = "Won X";

    // then
    assertEquals("Wona X", whoWin);
}

I have a problem with my tests on Java. So far I know if i put String sizeOfBoardString = "3\n2"; I should answear for 2 question from the program but there is still a query to put an answear.
To sum up I am trying to test the tictactoe program. I ask for the size of board and it take the value. But when I ask if computer or human, it tells me there is no value. But in my opinion it should be 2 because of that value: String sizeOfBoardString = "3\n2";
If I start  the program manually it works fine
public class StartGame {

    public void runGame(int boardSize, int boardSize2) {
        RealUser realUser = new RealUser();
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        OutputComputer outputComputer = new OutputComputer();
        Board board = new Board(boardSize, boardSize);
        outputComputer.computerOrHuman();
        int compOrHum = board.computerOrHuman();
        board.showFilledBoard();
}

And there is a calling a computerOrHuman()
public class Board {

    private char[][] values;
    private int rows;
    private int columns;
    List<Character> winnersX = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Character> winnersO = new ArrayList<>();

    public Board(int rows, int columns) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.values = new char[rows][columns];
    }
    public int computerOrHuman() {
        InputSelector inputSelector = new InputSelector();
        int ifHuman = inputSelector.computerOrHuman();
        return ifHuman;
    }
}

And inputer selector that contain scanner.nextLine()
public class InputSelector {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public int computerOrHuman() {
        int computerOrHuman = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        return computerOrHuman;
    }
}

What should I do to to code work?
That's the result of the code:
Welcome to TicTacToe!
Choose a type of game. Type 3 or 10
Do you want to play with computer(1) or human(2)?
No line found
public class OutputComputer {
    public void computerOrHuman() {
        System.out.println("Do you want to play with computer(1) or human(2)?");
    }
}


It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  When you debug your code, which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

David I am trying to test the tictactoe program. I ask for the size of board and it take the value. But when I ask if computer or human, it tells me there is no value. But in my opinion it should be 2 because of that value: String sizeOfBoardString = "3\n2";

Please don't editorialize.  When using a debugger, which specific operation in the code shown is not producing the result you expect?  What exact result is that operation producing?

There is a problem with that part
Do you want to play with computer(1) or human(2)?
No line found

"Do you want to play with computer(1) or human(2)?" - This string isn't in the code shown.  "No line found" - This string also isn't in the code shown.  Perhaps those messages are coming from some other code that you're not showing us?  Please update the question to clarify.

Just added the code

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

But strange thing is if I start the game it works fine. But on test it can't find the value

A Scanner reads input into a buffer. Only then, it can search for line terminators in that buffer, to process the “next line” you requested via scanner.nextLine().
In your manual run, the human user will provide input only when being asked for input. Therefore, the Scanner has only the current line to read. But when setting the input to fixed content, the first Scanner object will read the entire ByteArrayInputStream into its buffer on scanner.nextLine() and the next one will not see any input.
You have to design your software such that it uses only one Scanner object for one source of input. You may still have a class encapsulating the scanner, like your InputSelector but then, you must have only one instance of that class. With one Scanner instance, the next call of nextLine() will consider the already buffered data.

Some testing frameworks, like JUnit, might mark a test as passed or failed prematurely if there are incorrect assertions or missing verifications.
Ensure:
Assertions and verifications are placed correctly.
The test doesn’t conclude after testing the first function.
You can also test both the function seprately
